# Stress accent of бахмутчан, other words in -чан

Tags: наголос

I have been unable to locate the stress accent in the word бахмутчан.  Could someone please let me know which syllable has it?  And to make this of more general interest, do words in -чан have a regular pattern of stress accent?  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Heh, it's kinda the ironic situation, because for this suffix a stress pattern is easy, but not adding to the base of the word..

For the start, *-чан* is actually *-ч-ан-ин* where:

- The part *-ан-ин* is [*-ян-ин*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/-janin%D1%8A).

  If you left just *-ян* then it's plural during decletion where *-ин* is removed: singular *кий-ан-ин* but plural *кий-ан-и*, and if you remove *-и* here then you get Genetive or Accusative cases: *кий-ан*.
- The part *-ч-* isn't suffix but a changed part of a word base which end with *k* or *т*, and from their deriatives and some adjective suffixes.

  In case with *к*, because the sound cann't be palatalized, therefore *~к + янин* → *ч-ан-ин*. It happens in other situation too, for examples: *рук-а* but *руч-ати* or *руч-ка*.

  In the second case, it's easier to say *ч-анин* istead *т-янин* in some cases, it happens in verbs too: *плат-ити* but from *плат-ю* we get *плач-у*. But in this case we saved *т* too: *датчанин*, *бахмутчанин* etc where *тч* is actually *чч* in pronounce. There're no logic in the standard spelling, because from *д* — a voiced pair to *т* — you get just *ж* as in *горожанин* from *город* or *слобожанин* from *слобода*; while we have situation where there aren't changed: *громад-янин*, *єгипет-янин*, *освіт-янин* etc.

  Therefore *-ян-ин* can become as *-ан-ин* but with changed specific previous consonants or *й* which doesn't doubled. And dialects can have their own variatives.

  And labial sounds also cann't be palatalized but they doesn't change itself, therefore we have *словʼянин*, *острівʼянин* etc.
- An additional problem is figure out what is a word base, because usually we doesn't save *-ів* like in mentioned *Київ → киянин*, but from *Львів* you get *львівʼянин* not *львʼянин* which has some usage in non-standard spelling but with *харківʼянин* from *Харків* situation is more problematic.

So a dictionary form would be *бахмутчанин* or *бахмутянин* which you also can meet in usage.

---

What about the stress accent then the suffix [always](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky) make here: *-я́нин*.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful!

Comment: @JamesWard, just to make it clear: the wordform _бахмутча́н_ also exists, but that's just [genitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case) [plural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural) of the word _бахмутча́нин_ (you can see the whole declension table with stress accents for a similar word _полтавча́нин_ [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/полтавчанин#Declension_2)).